# Эмулятор планшета 7"

Tags: android, эмулятор

Знает ли кто нибудь эмулятор андроидовского планшета с 7" и 800х480 точек? Я имею ввиду что-бы добавить его в AVD.

Comment: При создании эмулятора можно указать любой размер экрана (там опция есть). Или вам необходима модель каого-лобо телефона?

Answer (score 2):

В окне `Create new AVD`, насколько я знаю, можно указывать размер экрана в пикселях. 
Соответственно, выставляете там разрешение `800х480` точек.

Тем более, что размеры **реального** экрана *(т.е в вашем случае, `7"`)*, здесь совершенно непринципиально. Можно экран `800x480` впихнуть в 2 дюйма, а можно и `240x320` растянуть на 20 дюймов.

Comment: Да дело в том, что-то планшет. А так у меня на телефоне такое разрешение

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что Вам просто нужно выбрать правильную версию андроида. Правильные планшеты работают на андроид 3.0 и выше. А вот телефоны работают на 2.*. Да, есть дешевые китайские планшеты на 2.*, но они обычноотличаются только лаунчером. И для программиста в большинстве случаев это не играет никакой роли.

Когда  будете создавать новое устройство, выберите версию апи не меньше 12. Если такой нет - там легко можно доустановить.

Comment: Делаю под планшет с андроидом 2.3.

Comment: а Вы думаете, что для планшета андроид какой то особенный? Чем не удовлетворяет текущий?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Android x86, к примеру, на эмуляторе VirtualBox.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "AndroidName" "CustomVideoMode1" "800х480x16"
```

Так можно задать режим разрешения, где AndroidName - имя виртуальной машины, а CustomVideoMode1 - имя режима.

Если в параметры ядра системы добавить аналогичную строку:

```
quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot_hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode vga=ask SRC=/android_src
```

то можно выбрать режим при загрузке.

Более подробно можно прочитать [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/130201/).